# How to have a horizontally scrollable list with lots of text to wrap?

Tags: html, css

Have a look at this : [fiddle on horizontal scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/V5zWT/12/)

What I want is to put a lot of text in a fixed size container and have the text wrap. When I change the text in the fiddle to contain a lot of text it does not wrap and goes over other items.

```
<div class="DocumentList">
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li class="DocumentItem">
        <span>Put lots of text here and it goes over the other items instead of wrapping</span>
    </li>
    <li class="DocumentItem">
        <span>Test Data1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="DocumentItem">
        <span>Test Data1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="DocumentItem">
        <span>Test Data1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="DocumentItem">
        <span>Test Data1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="DocumentItem">
        <span>Test Data1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="DocumentItem">
        <span>Test Data1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="DocumentItem">
        <span>Test Data1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="DocumentItem">
        <span>Test Data1</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So what I want is a list of divs which contain a lot of text (say div is 200 by 200) and there should be a horizontal scroll to access other items in the list.

Is there a way to do this with this fiddle or with any way?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V5zWT/615/ is what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this;

```
.DocumentList {
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    padding: 0 15px;
    white-space: nowrap; // nowrap here
}

.DocumentItem {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:0;
    height:200px;
    display: inline-block; // inline block
    width: 200px; // set width here
    white-space: normal; // wrap whitespace here
    vertical-align: top; // align elements to the top
}
```

This will allow your text to wrap inside the LI and have a scroll on the UL

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V5zWT/616/)

EDIT -

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V5zWT/617/)

Comment: Excellent. Spent two hours and I was not able to get anything close to what you managed :). Well done. Now, is there a way to keep the border all the way around? Currently, I do not see the bottom border? So I need some container (with a border) that holds my text.

Comment: @JD. Please see my edit. The borders was getting cut off as the containers had a set height of 200px. I have removed the height property on the container and the items but you could keep a min-height if wanted :)

Comment: Thanks for your help rocket :).